# Need to retrieve file from a remote server in PHP script. Folder restricted to root. Root doesn't have scp access. What can I do?

Tags: php, apache, security, ssh, scp

I have a big list of servers. Using a PHP script, I need to get the apache2 access logs from each server. I had originally tested this with a test file and my webuser using SCP and it worked great, but at the time I didn't realize that root can't use SCP by default, so when I switched over to grab the actual files... it failed.

Apache2 logs are protected and can only be accessed by root. This is fine, as I have the credentials. However - I cannot just use SCP with root as root doesn't have access to SCP, and I can't go in and give spc permission to root on each server. I also can't change the log permissions so that my webuser can access it.

Is there some sort of workaround to this?

I've considered using exec to simply ssh into each remote server as root, and use scp in reverse to push back down to my local server - right now I'm working on my local and I don't have a static IP to specify, is there a way to specify the host? Perhaps I could ssh is as root, copy the log files to a temp directory that webuser can access, exit, scp back in as webuser and copy the files down?

Do either of these things make sense?

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Your problem makes sense. It probably would be quickest to set up a cron job to move the log file into a location where SCP can reach them. That way you don't have to log in to do it. I've had similar problems and ended up moving the files and editing their permissions.

Comment: How is root prevented from using scp? Without knowing precisely what restrictions are in place on the server, it's difficult to suggest another approach.

Comment: @kenster - From what I'm reading, by default in Linux, root doesn't have scp access. I can't even scp an unprotected file with root, I get permission denied, but it works with my webuser. Unfortunately I can't go in and give access on every server I need to hit, so I'm hoping to find another way around.

Comment: @McRed -  Thanks! I will likely try something like that.

Comment: It's not uncommon for root to be completely blocked from logging in through ssh, or to only permit root login using an ssh key. Permitting root login through ssh but specifically blocking scp doesn't sound like a common configuration. It seems sort of pointless since there are lots of ways to transfer a file through an ssh connection.

Comment: @kenster - sorry, just checked, and ssh is blocked as well. So I would need to ssh as my webuser and su to root.